# vi / vim tutorial recommendations

Tags: vim, vi, documentation

Being a common tool for *nix System Administrators, I'm looking for recommendations for vi/vim tutorials.  After seeing this ['how do I do [this] in vim'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/235839/428779) question in Stack Overflow, I realize that I have yet to find a helpful-to-beginners tutorial which teaches not only the basic commands, but also ties in the logical mindset of vim (no snickering, emacs users).  I have seen plenty of cheat-sheets (with varying levels of helpfulness), but they never tie in how to modify commands.

An example is that I know that to delete a line you use `dd`, but to delete a set number of lines use (three in this example), use `d3d`.

Another is that if you want a new line (to push the current line down) use a capital `O`, but to insert a line after this line, use lowercase `o`.  (I think of it as the smaller, meeker version is more polite, while the big one shoves other lines out of it's way.)

Tying those together, to copy a line, use `yy`, and p where you want to paste.  If you want to copy multiple lines (say 7), do `y7y`.  Capital `P` to shove the current line down, or lowercase `p` to paste after the current line.

What are some 'tying it all together' tutorials?

Comment: I'm surprised that this is being marked off-topic.  Especially as vim is available on almost every platform (aside from Cisco, perhaps) which SysAds may be needed.  Would it be better served on another site or as a wiki?

Comment: (or are the close votes coming from emacs lovers?)

Comment: I'm surprised that someone with 4k rep would consider it on topic in serverfault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am working on an interactive tutorial for basic commands. You can find it at: http://www.openvim.com
There is already a sandbox page that has a context sensitive menu, so that if you press '5' you can see what possibilities you have after that, e.g. 5w.

There will be new concept, a teaching box, later on, which deals with the wholesome experience of Vim; i.e. opening of files, splitting windows, etc.

Most of the basic functionality is there already. Currently I'm adding visual and visual block modes.

And hopefully I have energy to add some Vim based games.

Comment: That sounds awesome, but you're not the first persons to mention it, but I personally would be thrilled about that!  Thanks for working on that!

Comment: @gWaldo You're welcome! I am happy to hear people find it useful :)

Answer (score 8):

Run `vimtutor`. It's a great tutorial that will give you just the right amount of knowledge necessary to get started with vim.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try the command 'vimtutor' for a tutorial. I came across this recently which seems neat: [Interactive VIM tutorial](http://www.openvim.com/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3):

Typing ":help" in vi(m) will open up quite a world of information for you. Also, you may want to check out this tutorial: http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Learn-Vim-Progressively/

Comment: That does look like an excellent tutorial.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer dead tree materials, [O'Reilly is hard to beat.](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529833.do)

Comment: Ha!  I forgot about that!

Answer (score 2):

Derek Wyatt has a [series of tutorial videos](http://www.derekwyatt.org/vim/vim-tutorial-videos/) that I've found quite helpful. They cover basic stuff through fairly advanced, and are in short manageable portions.

Answer (score 1):

It probably depends on what kind of learner you are but I don't think OpenVim is more useful than simply running `$ vimtutor` : it's longer, less exhaustive and too gimmicky. Plus it's a very poor and limited Vim emulation. Use the real vim instead.

From your question I gather that you already know the basics, anyway. Openvim is very basic so you won't learn many things from it.

The next step after `vimtutor` is to exercise on real text and real code with real vim.

That's when you'll notice by yourself that everything is tied together: using vim is speaking a language with a rich vocabulary and a very simple set of grammar rules (with their exceptions).

Answer (score 0):

to be honest, i'd advise learning the commands when you find you need them. Everyone works in different ways, and you shouldnt really allow a tutorial to give you one mind set.

I say edit how you want, and look into commands with a view to making that way easier. For example, i do a fair bit of python coding, so to me code folding and indentation is key, for others searching is more important so they focus on those commands.

Comment: That is what I have been doing, but I'm looking for the 'tie it all together' bit.